# Implementing Undo with redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

If an action `removeItem(itemId)` is fired from the UI it should first delete the corresponding item from the state and then call the associated saga. If the saga fails it should reset the state to it's original state.

I was wondering if you can append information to the action payload within the reducers then fire a `failed` action from the saga with the same payload. This is assuming that the reducer will always be fired first (Is it true?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't dispatch from inside your reducer. A reducers job is to take current state, an action, and return new state from the reduction of the two. That's it. What you're trying to do can be accomplished by a strategy like the following:

1. Use `itemId` to get a reference to the item and store it locally.
2. Dispatch action to remove item from store based on id.
3. Call associated saga.
4. If it fails, add locally stored item from step 1 back into the store. If successful, remove reference to item from step 1.

Comment: @ankit_m Yes, this is how I would handle this situation.

Comment: But where do I keep the deleted data? Say two items are deleted back to back. Where and how do you store the removed data inorder to restore if the saga fails?

Comment: @ankit_m before you delete the data from the store you would get the data so that you could store it locally outside of your store incase you need to re-add it. You could push each deleted item into an array, and remove them from the array as the saga's succeed, or dispatch actions to re-add them to store as sagas fail. Either way, after a saga succeeds or fails you would remove the local data associated with that itemId.